# Building Guassian quadrature of order 2

Tags: computational-mathematics, lagrange-interpolation

Given the weight function $w(t) \equiv 1$, for $t\in [0,1]$ build the Gaussian quadrature formula of order $2$.

The formula in this case has the form

$$ \int_0^1 f(\tau)d\tau \approx b f(c) $$

For this, I find an orthogonal polynomial $1-2t$, whose root is $c:=\frac{1}{2}$. To find $b$, I need to take the interpolated polynomial $$ t-\frac{1}{2} $$

if I'm not mistaken, since

$$p_j(t) = \prod\limits_{k=1, k\ne j}^\nu\frac{t-c_k}{c_j-c_k}$$

where $j=1,...,\nu$. In this case we have just one $c_k$, so it looks like we can just take $t-\frac{1}{2}$.

Then $$ b = \int_0^1 (\tau -\frac{1}{2})d\tau$$ which is just $0$. So something I'm doing is not right. I think I'm erring on the interpolating polynomial side. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your case you are constructing 0th order polynomial which is 1, and not linear.